# Is there a third-party tools to convert Eclipse settings to Netbeans?

Tags: ide, eclipse, netbeans

I usually use Eclipse but I'll need to work with Netbeans for a while since I'm starting a JavaFX project.

I can't fathom having to re-map every single shortcut and setting. Is there a tool somewhere that can import Eclipse settings for me?

Comment: There is the [e(fx)clipse plugin for JavaFX](http://efxclipse.org/), so, if you prefer Eclipse, you could use that rather than NetBeans.

Answer (score 1):

This might help:
http://wiki.netbeans.org/EclipseToNetBeans

Comment: It helps. I also noticed that there was a "Eclipse keybindings" presets in the settings. There is still a lot of settings left behind though, so I'll leave the question open in case someone come up with anything.